# Android emulator screenshot resolution does not match virtual device resolution

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to get screenshots of my cross platform app at specific resolutions (for App Store submission). I'm working in Windows.

One obvious way of doing this is to create an Android emulator for a device with the target resolution. For instance, here's a device with 2688x1242 resolution:

[image: Android 2688]

However, if I take a screenshot on this device via the emulator's screenshot button:

[image]

The resulting image is always 1080p (portrait: 1080x1920).

How can I take a screenshot at the virtual device's native resolution?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I have an emulated device with a resolution of 1080x2340, but my generated screenshots are 1080x2280... I tried both the emulator screenshot capture and the logcat screenshot capture.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem: I created a Pixel 5 emulator with a resolution of 1080x2340, but my screenshots always were 1080x2280.

I now noticed that the emulator's default display somehow was a Pixel 4 display with the wrong resolution.

I was able to fix this problem by editing my virtual device the following way:

1. Go to **AVD Manager**
2. Right click your device and choose **Edit**
3. Select **Show Advanced Settings**
4. Scroll to **Device Frame** section
5. Uncheck **Enable Device Frame**
6. Select **No Skin** for **Custom skin definition** (there does not seem to be a pre-made Pixel 5 skin currently)

Now I don't have a device frame anymore on my emulator but the screenshots are generated with the expected resolution.

Comment: I had to check the "Enable device frame" to get the same resolution but a good hint

Answer (score 0):

Try the screen capture button provided in logcat.

Detailed steps are given in the official docs:  https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue today and managed to solve it. I had an AVD created using Visual Studio with dimensions set to 2688x1242. However, I noticed  that in Android Studio its dimensions appear to be 1920x1080. I created another AVD using Android Studio and now it works - the screenshots are of proper size.